# Classcast Exception for javax.crypto.CipherSpi due to different modules

Tags: java

I am moving a app to Java 11 which uses encryption.  When I try to run the tests I get the following error.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: 
class com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher$General 
cannot be cast to class javax.crypto.CipherSpi 
(com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher$General is in module 
java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; 
javax.crypto.CipherSpi is in unnamed module of loader
org.powermock.core.classloader.javassist.JavassistMockClassLoader@4c1d9d4b)
```

I don't understand what it means or how to resolve it.

Comment: Possibly related - https://stackoverflow.com/q/60872965/1098361

Comment: After reviewing the possibly related post It seems to me that the AESCipher$General comes from java.base classloader and it is finding javax.crypto.CipherSpi in the powermock.core classloader.  If I understand it correctly.   I have looked in the powermock dependencies (actually all my dependencies) and I cannot find one that contains javax.crypto.CipherSpi.

Comment: Have you tried a simple test where you cast `AESCipher$General` to `CipherSpi` all by itself? Breaking things down as small as you can can help resolve issues.

Comment: When I try to create the class it says the com.sun.crypto.provider package does not exist.

Comment: I am assuming that is because java.base does not export that package.

Comment: I re-configured my test case and have identified the issue as being a problem when using the @RunWIth(PowerMockRunner.class) annotation.  If I do not use this annotation the test runs.  If I add the annotation it throws the error listed above.

Comment: Good troubleshooting and thanks for letting the SO community know! May help others or yourself in the future!

Answer (score 2):

After some helpful direction I was able to track the issue down to happening only when the @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) was used.  To resolve the issue I added the @PowerMockIgnore({"javax.crypto.*"}) annotation.  This resolved all the errors and the test now works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This helped, mockito was trying to mock some these objects which was leading to failure. Adding @PowerMockIgnore does help.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).